# gmail sender address? domain-transfer?

Tags: domain, gmail

i don't have a clue and i'm confused anyway.

i created a website for a client - we did a domaintransfer to a new hosting provider.
all of their 6 employees had an email address like name.surname@domainname.com. However they are sending all their emails from GMAIL. They are even signing in with name.surname@domainname.com. They are not signing in with a regular Gmail account like @gmail.com. How is this even possible? Since we did the Domaintransfer to a new hosting provider yesterday however, none of their email addresses aren't working any longer.

It's probably because i haven't registered those email-users on the new hosting providers website, right?

Any idea what i have to do, to fix this problem asap. Do i have to create all those email-users on the email-admin-panel on the new providers website? What password do i set? The same they are signing in on gmail? I still don't get how they can sign in with a specific domain on gmail? When they send emails from gmail, the sender-address is also name.surname@domainname.com and not some @gmail.com address.

any ideas and solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Ouch. Sounds like they had/have a Google Apps set up. I administer a couple; they're great. They had special entries in their DNS to make the email routing and the non-gmail.com login work. It sounds like you switched DNS to a "standard" set up, and thus this all stopped working. To get things working, you need to get the correct entries back into the DNS.

I suggest looking at their old DNS config, if you still have access to it. If not, check out the docs for Google Apps, and do the set up accordingly.  You might need admin access to their Google Apps account to find out the correct DNS entries.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to set mx-records at the new provider. Google has a guide either [here](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=22229&topic=22230#148937) if your provider is not on the list then [here](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=33915)

Answer (score 0):

Were they using Google Apps for their e-mail? It's possible to set up a branded version of GMail under a custom domain name. (It's a pretty hot topic in start-ups these days.) In order for it to work, certain DNS records need some magic values. You'll want to make sure you transfer over these records too. Specifically, there'll be a CNAME record that's something like "google2345sd8972sdfa345.domain.com" that redirects to Google. That's where you should look at first.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like they were using Google Apps for their email service, and when you changed hosting providers, some DNS records for your client's domain was pointed at the new host instead of Google's servers for webmail and incoming SMTP.

Probably, all you need to do is change the relevant DNS records back to point at Google.
Though if the MX record was pointed away from Google, there's probably mail piling up at
the new ISP that will need to be migrated back to Google somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems they are using Google Apps for their email services. When you change the hosting provider you also have to update the MX records for that domain in hosting control panel for using Google Apps mail service. Get the MX records [here](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=33352)